# Non printable PDF

Tags: pdf, itext

I've generated a PDF using Itext which I can open but when I try to print I get an error saying than the document is not printable. The document is generated without any non-printable flag.

Any hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the print option in Adobe Reader is not disabled then the document has no print restrictions. If the error appears when you try to print the document, it is possible that the page content is damaged. I've seen PDF files that Adobe Reader could display but it showed an error when trying to print or save them.

Comment: Seems to be that this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

this can only happen if you change the permission of
the file.
Did you perhaps copy a PdfStamper sample that has a line disabling the
print

unless

There are 10 entries under Document Restrictions Summary in the security tab.
in PdfWriter,
set
    ALLOW_PRINTING = 2052